# Running remote script effects to change parameters

Tags: bash, perl

I've a simple bash script to run the parameter as a command on the server, the necessity for this i am creating the required command as a string on the other server and trying to execute it remotely.

```
PROFILE=/coremedia/home/picroot/.profile
source $PROFILE
cmd=$1
shift
eval $cmd "$@"
```

the parameter i am sending to script :

`/coremedia/pic-cms-tools/bin/cm publish -u admin -p admin -t "/Config/Static Texts/PDF Texts/pdf.eudatasheet.ocEnergyConsConvAlone" "/Config/Static Texts/PDF Texts/pdf.eudatasheet.ocEnergyConsForcedAlone`"

The debug screen when i am running the scriipt locally, works perfectly with the `''` signs..

```
/coremedia/pic-cms-tools/bin/cm publish -u admin -p admin -t '/Config/Static Texts/PDF Texts/pdf.eudatasheet.ocEnergyConsConvAlone' '/Config/Static Texts/PDF Texts/pdf.eudatasheet.ocEnergyConsForcedAlone'
```

when i'm running the same script via ssh with backticks remotely with the same parameter above `$cmd` :

```
@lines = `ssh "$user"@"$host" "bash -x myscript.sh $cmd"`;
```

Debug screen shows me running command like :

```
 /coremedia/pic-cms-tools/bin/cm publish -u admin -p admin -t /Config/Static Texts/PDF Texts/pdf.eudatasheet.ocEnergyConsConvAlone /Config/Static Texts/PDF Texts/pdf.eudatasheet.ocEnergyConsForcedAlone
```

without the  `''` signs. Why does it change the parameters ?

I've tried many configurations on my side to handle the string but i've still couldn't reach a solution, obviously i am missing a small critical thing...

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Comment: I was edited my old question but running the script remotely is a new task to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to escape your quotes?

```
/coremedia/pic-cms-tools/bin/cm publish -u admin -p admin -t \"/Config/Static Texts/PDF Texts/pdf.eudatasheet.ocEnergyConsConvAlone\" \"/Config/Static Texts/PDF Texts/pdf.eudatasheet.ocEnergyConsForcedAlone\"
```

You can also try something like this:

```
/coremedia/pic-cms-tools/bin/cm publish -u admin -p admin -t "'/Config/Static Texts/PDF Texts/pdf.eudatasheet.ocEnergyConsConvAlone'" "'/Config/Static Texts/PDF Texts/pdf.eudatasheet.ocEnergyConsForcedAlone'"
```